# C++: variable declaration with 3 asterisks

Tags: c++, pointers

```
double ***x;
```

what does it mean to declare declare a variable with three asterisks? Is this a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a double?

Comment: I feel like "yep" isn't a proper answer. So here's a comment. 
Yep.

Comment: @Robert: +1 for FGITW. :-) (No upvotes for all the SCITE answers. ;-))

Comment: @Chris, I've never seen these shorthands before: I have to ask what they mean.

Comment: @trutheality: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a double.

Comment: +1 for having the guts to make this community wiki to provide an "accept"able answer while the real answer was given as a comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

For syntax questions such as this try [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/), having it bookmarked saved me some time with pointers to functions that return a const int * const T, note that it uses C, though it recognizes things like references giving a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a double.

Either a big multi-dimensional array, or just many levels of pointer indirection.